# String values are not appending to textbox in Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, windows

I have a windows form application in which I am using ms access database to retrieve values.

Now as per my need on Load event I have to populate the textbox from the values retrieved from ms access database but while setting the string value to textbox it is coming empty.

Here is my code..

```
string ipaddress, textfileSaveLocation;
string Port;

public TechsoftIPCommunicator()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\techsoft\\PROJECTTT.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=techsoft");
    OleDbCommand cmd;
    Conn.Open();

    cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from IPCOMSettings", Conn);
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        ipaddress = dr.GetString(1);
        Port = dr.GetString(2);
        textfileSaveLocation = dr.GetString(3);
    }

    ipaddress = textBox1.Text;
    Port = textBox2.Text;
    textfileSaveLocation = textBox3.Text;
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your issue is that you are not actually populating the textboxes but instead you are populating the strings with the text of the textboxes!

```
 textBox1.Text = ipaddress;
 textBox2.Text = Port;
 textBox3.Text = textfileSaveLocation;
```

That should populate them now

Answer (score 0):

Your not populating the textboxes you are putting the value of them into a variable. 
Change:

```
    ipaddress = textBox1.Text;
    Port = textBox2.Text;
    textfileSaveLocation = textBox3.Text;
```

To

```
    textBox1.Text = ipaddress;
    textBox2.Text = Port;
    textBox3.Text = textfileSaveLocation;
```

Hope this helps.